# How would I implement this method using a futex?

Tags: c++, futex

This method (I realize the function might need some extra parameters):

```
void waitUntilNotEqual(volatile int* addr, int value)
{
    while (*addr == value) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the man page: http://ds9a.nl/futex-manpages/futex2.html and let us know if there's something you still need after that.  One thing I am not sure of from your question is whether you intend to have another function that informs this one that the value has been updated, or if you prefer to use timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to the use of futexes but here's a solution that I think should work. Just be warned that I haven't tested this at all and it could be made faster with a few more tweaks.

```
void waitUntilNotEqual(volatile int* addr, int value) {
  while (*addr == value) {
    futex(addr, FUTEX_WAIT, value, 0, 0, 0);
  }
}

void changeValue (volatile int* addr, int newValue) {
  int oldValue = *addr;
  if (oldValue != newValue) {
    *addr = newValue;
    futex(addr, FUTEX_WAKE, INT_MAX, 0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

In order for this to work properly, all modification of the address passed to `waitUntilNotEqual` should be done through `changeValue`. The `INT_MAX` value in the `FUTEX_WAKE` call indicates that it should wake all threads waiting on this futex. The if statement in the `changeValue` function is an optimisation that avoids pointless wakeups. Finally, the `FUTEX_WAIT` call needs to be kept in a loop because it might return spuriously from signals.

I should also point out that you didn't give much details about the problem you're trying to solve which means that this piece of code is probably only correct for the very simplest of use cases. If you want something better adapted to your current problem then I need more details (number of threads, context in which `waitUntilNotEqual` and `changeValue` is called, number of possible concurrent threads in `waitUntilNotEqual` or `changeValue`, etc.)

If you're interested in learning more about how to properly use futexes, I recommend the [Futexes Are Tricky](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/futex.pdf) paper.